# how to share a global Queue between a normal function and a route request function in python fastapi

Tags: python, fastapi, uvicorn

```py
import queue
import threading
import time
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI
task_queue = queue.Queue()
app = FastAPI()
@app.get("/")
def hello_world():
    task_queue.put('task')
    print(task_queue, task_queue.qsize())
    return {"Hello": "World"}
def handle_tasks():
    while True:
        print(task_queue, task_queue.qsize())
        time.sleep(5)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    threading.Thread(target=handle_tasks, args=()).start()
    uvicorn.run("test:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=8000, workers=1)
```

Why there are two different Queue object in my program, I want them to be only one.

Or there are any simple way to do this: "add a task by a http request and handle the tasks in a queue in a normal function"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import logging
import time
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi_utils.tasks import repeat_every

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
app = FastAPI()
counter = 0

@app.get('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello'

@app.on_event("startup")
@repeat_every(seconds=1, logger=logger, wait_first=True)
def periodic():
    global counter
    print('counter is', counter)
    counter += 1
```

https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/520#issuecomment-667428023